# Content Porter Import Issue - SDL Tridion 2013

Tags: content-porter-2013

I am trying to import content using SDL Tridion Content Porter 2013.

I moved all the Schemas, and Categories and Keywords.
I was trying to move close to 600 items for each Category and was trying to move one Category and associated content which is multimedia Component. The export package size is 77.5 MB

It fails while doing import and get following error

> The Trasaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposted. The transcation must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statements.
>   Transactional import failed. No Changes will be commited.

I increased the timeout on COM+ and increased .NET transcation on CMS server and edit the `machine.config` and increased the timeout. Still having this issue.

We are using SQL Server 2012, windows Server2012 and SDL Tridion 2013.

Please provide  me some details on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Do you have some stackTrace?
It looks like some bug...for further analyzing my suggestion - try to uncomment in web.config of the CP and importExport.exe.cfg logging for XmlResponderFacade - you can find it in the end of both configs ("Uncomment sources below for logging XmlResponderFacade requests and responses. Path to file must exists."). It must help with analyzing if you really have Tridion 2013.

Comment: Could you try upping the log level to log everything (consult the content porter manual on how to do this) and posting the relevant lines from the CP_Import.log? That may show you which item is causing the failure.

Comment: Thanks for the update rob, I did update the content porter log level to log all, each time when I try to move the export package which contains many items and all dependency are checked before I did  export and import  and the package size  range from 600kb to  77MB still have this timeout issue. I see on the log it says there is issue with some dependency  but when I check the component which failed I see no dependency , that component is just linked to the page .  I am trying to move only the component or content from the content publication.

Comment: When I try to select less items that can be components  or category etc , the import works just fine.  i need to know the timeout settings that need to be done in case if that is the issue.  I increased the timeout of component services on both DB server  and CMS server
I Uncomment sources below for logging XmlResponderFacad but it’s not writing anything , let me check why it’s not writing the log.
Please let me know is there any time out setting that will help in fixing this issue

Comment: Try stoping and restarting the services.. I ended up with a similar issue, and thats the first thing i did.. and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

as you indicated in your first post, there may be multimedia items which are being imported as well.
Here are two approaches then, exclude such dependencies so that you only import the items you need or increase the time allowed for this transaction.

On the Content Manager server on which you are importing, can you edit the file [Tridion HOME]\config\Tridion.ContentManager.config ?
In the node    change the transactionTimeout parameter to a larger value that can support the size of the files you are importing.  This parameter is measured in seconds.

Below is an example, but bear in mind the transactionTimeout value might be different depending on your own requirements.

```
<tridion.contentmanager> 
<repository categoryEnumerationLimit="0" /> 
<license licenseFilePath="license.xml" /> 
<session transactionTimeout="500" /> <!-Default 60 seconds --> 
</tridion.contentmanager>
```

To limit the amount of items exported or imported, checkout this tutorial on www.sdltridionworld.com, especially Part 4- Detailed Process, look for the right-click popup menu showing the "Selected Children Only" option:
https://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/using-content-porter-2009-sp1-for-dtap-4.aspx