# Content Porter import issue: request channel timed out

Tags: content-porter-2013

I have an issue when importing a zip.file (2.29 GB) into Tridion 2013 SP1 with Content Porter 2013 sp1.

[image: error message]

I know that it is possible to increase time-outs in  web.config files. I already tried that in Tridion/Web/Web.config and \Tridion\Content Porter\ImportExportService\Web.config but this didn't work out.

What are the other configuration locations (if any) that I should look at?

UPDATE:

In \Tridion\Content Porter\ImportExportService\Web.config I added:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                maxBufferSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="02:00:00"></binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I also added the maxTimeout of 1 hour to the machine.config, as explained [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dincrease%2520timeout&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1423097173512&currentQuery=increase%2520timeout&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-D1C6115E-0E56-4153-9FE1-58E1D3DEE28F&query=increase%2520timeout&scope=&filename=GUID-D1C6115E-0E56-4153-9FE1-58E1D3DEE28F.xml&docid=GUID-D1C6115E-0E56-4153-9FE1-58E1D3DEE28F&inner_id=&tid=cac07d0c-3b82-41d8-a97b-9c05507456f2&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false).

So that the SendTimeout is 2 hours now. Not sure what binding name I have to use. My question is:
In which file do I have to set the increased timeout value? And what kind of timeout it is that causes this error?

UPDATE 10-02:

I don't have a proper solution for now. Just divided the package in to smaller pieces. Send this issue to SDL Support. I will let you know when I have the answer ;)

Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: What exactly did you change in those web configs, can you edit your question, and add the bits you changed?

Comment: Hi Bart, I updated my question. Should there be an Web.config in my \Tridion\Content Porter\ImportExportService folder? I don't have that. 

I also found this on GitHub (https://gist.github.com/DominicCronin/9088882#file-gistfile1-xml), there is an Send and Receive timeout in there. Where can I place that file?

Comment: It seems from image problem occurs on uploading package, but you have updated basicHttpBinding. I think you need to change receiveTimeout for "ImportExport_StreamUpload_basicHttpBinding" (by default its value 30 minutes).
Btw, how long it takes before you get an exception ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you increased transaction timeouts in `machine.config`? If not follow [documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dincrease%2520timeout&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1423097173512&currentQuery=increase%2520timeout&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-D1C6115E-0E56-4153-9FE1-58E1D3DEE28F&query=increase%2520timeout&scope=&filename=GUID-D1C6115E-0E56-4153-9FE1-58E1D3DEE28F.xml&docid=GUID-D1C6115E-0E56-4153-9FE1-58E1D3DEE28F&inner_id=&tid=cac07d0c-3b82-41d8-a97b-9c05507456f2&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false) to do it. It is well documented there.

Also check related question [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3956/content-porter-import-issue-sdl-tridion-2013)

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I already did that, will add that to my post.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like a send timeout on the client (and not a receive timeout on the server) so modifying the server's config files will most likely not help.

Since CP is a clickonce application the config file does not have a fixed location (on my system its "C:\Users\bdommelen\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\O2JO0ER5.034\0L6K4GHE.ANH\cp.a..tion_cefdd28298bce0cb_0003.0004_c1336882d2b3b295\Config\system.servicemodel.bindings.config"). You can find the location where your content porter client application is installed from the windows task manager (process: cp.exe).

I would suggest increasing the timeout values and size limits there.

Comment: Hi thank you for help. I located this files and set a sendTimeout but that didn't fix the issue either. I send the issue to SDL, will update this question when I have the answer.